# Identifying points in lines of text

Tags: java, file-io, ascii

I have a java program that reads lines of a text file into a buffer and when the buffer is full it outputs the lines so that after all lines have been through the buffer the output is partially sorted.

The output will be in blocks of lines so I need a way to mark the end of each block in the output. Since the output is lines of text I'm not sure what character to use as a marker since the text can contain any characters. I'm thinking of using the ascii null or unit separator but I'm not sure if this would be reliable since it could also be in text.

Comment: may be you can post some code you tried in order identify the issue.

Comment: Well, if your output file will have separable "records", it's not a text document; it's structured. There are many structured file formats. Pick one that can separate records while allowing the text records to have any character. (BTW—XML directly is not an option because it doesn't allow certain characters.) It is unclear what characteristics your output file needs to have. Perhaps it needs to be append-able? Does some other program read it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Map, so you can set a key for every buffergroup something like that

```
Hash<int,Buffer> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are not sure how to discriminate lines, I suggest you take a look at a sentence tokenizer tool which is usually used in NLP. These programs contain patterns that discriminate lines from each other. That way, you can send all your date through and get the lines without worrying about wich character to use. There are plenty libraries for Java which does the job perfectly (Assuming your text is in English)